# How to get exif data from URL in react?

Tags: reactjs, exif

lets say i wanted to get an `exif` data from an image `url` in react, how the best approach to do this? is there any library that can help me achieve this?

let say i wanted to get the `exif` data of this image:

https://www.exiv2.org/include/img_1771.jpg

how to do that?

i have tried looking around only to find ways to get `exif` data from a local image. how to do it with `url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [blueimp-load-image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) you can do this:

```
loadImage(
  fileOrBlobOrUrl,
  function (img, data) {
    console.log('Original image head: ', data.imageHead)
    console.log('Exif data: ', data.exif) // requires exif extension
    console.log('IPTC data: ', data.iptc) // requires iptc extension
  },
  { meta: true }
)
```